# How to refresh Tkinter canvas to regrab area for OCR after clicking to a next page?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a project where I need to drag and select a particular area on the screen, extract the text from it using OCR, and save the extracted text to a Notepad file. Then, I want to click a pre-defined area to navigate to the next page, refresh the Tkinter canvas to reflect the new page, and re-grab the same area to extract text again. This process should continue in a loop.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import subprocess
import time  # Import the time module

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

class CaptureScreenshot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.withdraw()  # Hide main window
        # ... rest of your code ...

    def refresh_canvas(self):
        self.screenshot_np = pyautogui.screenshot()
        self.screenshot_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.screenshot_np)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.screenshot_img, anchor=tk.NW)

def click_predefined_area(x, y):
    # Move the mouse to the specified coordinates
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    # ... rest of your code ...

def main():
    global screenshot_captor
    screenshot_captor = CaptureScreenshot()
    # ... rest of your code ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have attempted to perform a canvas refresh using the `refresh_canvas` method, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. As I am fairly new to working with GUIs, I suspect I might be overlooking something. How can I achieve the desired functionality of refreshing the Tkinter canvas to regrab the same area for OCR after clicking to a next page?